# Percentage chance with two identical independent events each having the same percentage chance

Tags: probability

I have two sacks, each having a 60% chance for me to draw a winner from. The sacks are identical and I have only 1 draw from each sack.
What is the percentage chance that i draw a winner after i draw once from each sack?  More importantly, HOW do i figure this out?  I have googled numerous sites and either get hugely complex equations with two unknowns or super simple fraction x fraction answers that are different.

Comment: Can you find the probability that you draw no winner?

Comment: The probability of event $A$ or $B$ occurring is written as $Pr(A\cup B)$ and the probability of event $A$ and $B$ occurring is written as $Pr(A\cap B)$.  You have principle of inclusion-exclusion: $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$ and you have definition of independence $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$ (*remember, this equation is false for dependent events*), so you get the probability of drawing a winner from at least one of your sacks as $0.6+0.6-0.6\cdot 0.6$

Comment: The "*hugely complex equations*" that I give above really should be learned as they are used very regularly.

Comment: Sorry but I have to laugh.  I would never use this equation on a regular basis.  I just wanted to know because I am playing a computer game.  I'm a tree trimmer :).  Yes it IS a hugely complex equation to me just as the intricacies of trimming a 100 foot tall oak tree might be for you.  I do thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

The probability that you do not win is if you don't draw a winner from either sack, and that is given by $\frac{40}{100}\times\frac{40}{100}$. Subtract that from $1$ and you get the probability that you win.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Both answers above gave me 84% which was exactly what I was looking for!  Just fyi i was asking because i had two choices. Choice number 1 was the 2 sack example above and Choice number 2 was just 1 sack with a 90% chance.  I had to complete a longer job to get the 90% sack than I did to get the 2 60% sacks so I was trying to get a general idea of efficiency.  And all for a dang computer game lol.  Learned a lot here!  Thank you both!